# How can i add bytearrays In python?

Tags: python, hex, addition, shellcode

I'm new in python.
I have a bytearray of shellcode:

```
a=bytearray('\x31\xcb\x50\x69').
```

What i have to do is to +1 to every each of them to have this result:

```
bytearray('\x32\xcc\x51\x6a').
```

Any good ideas how I can achieve these in python?

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: What's to happen if one of the bytes is `0xff`?

Comment: Well, the procedure has to be reversible. 
So it has to wrap around, so when i'll reverse it, it can go back to 0xff.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a=bytearray('\x31\xcb\x50\x69')
>>> a
bytearray(b'1\xcbPi')    # repr uses a different but equivalent representation
>>> bytearray(x + 1 for x in a)
bytearray(b'2\xccQj')
```

You will need to consider what it means to +1 to `0xff`

for example

```
bytearray((x + 1) % 0xff for x in a)  # wrap around
```

or

```
bytearray(min(x + 1), 0xff) for x in a)  # limit to 0xff
```

It's probably faster to use the `translate` method if you are doing a few of these

```
>>> trans_table = bytearray(range(1, 256)) + '\x00'
>>> a.translate(trans_table)
bytearray(b'2\xccQj')
```

If you want to print the arrays to look like that, use the `repr()` function

```
>>> print a
1�Pi
>>> print repr(a)
bytearray(b'1\xcbPi')
```

Comment: Hooray for `translate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Not sure what i do wrong.
I tried all the solutions provider and they all give weird results like that:
1�P�    or   2�Q�
....?

Comment: @Dionka, that is how your console is attempting to represent the bytearray when you print it. `print` calls `__str__` on the bytearray. You can use `repr` to get the representation seen here

Answer (score 2):

```
a = bytearray('\x31\xcb\x50\x69')
a = bytearray(b + 1 if b < 255 else 0 for b in a)
```

Change the `0` to `255` if you want to clip the value rather than wrappping back around to zero.

Comment: These gave me this result:
"  2�Qj  "

Why did that happen?

Comment: Those are the bytes in your bytearray, interpreted as characters. Try your original value, it'll look similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
a=bytearray('\x31\xcb\x50\x69')
new_a = bytearray(b + 1 for b in a)


for b in new_a:
    print('{:02x}'.format(b))
```

Outputs:

```
32
cc
51
6a
```